# mix two sql queries

Tags: sql

I want to mix 2 sql queries, one to get total amount in a particular year, and other to know the amount in a particular month of a particular year

```
SELECT SUM(money) As Anual FROM Deposito WHERE Year(FechaDeposito)=2011

SELECT SUM(money) As monthly FROM Deposito WHERE Year(FechaDeposito)= 2011 AND Month(FechaDeposito)=10
```

How to do that in the most efficent way ?

Comment: What is the SQL dialect that you're using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply combining your two queries would give

```
SELECT SUM(money) As Anual,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month(FechaDeposito)=10 THEN money else 0 end) as monthly
  FROM Deposito
 WHERE Year(FechaDeposito)=2011
```

It will perform terribly however. Ideally you want an index on `FechaDeposito`, and to construct date ranges to test against instead of running functions over the column, e.g.

```
SELECT SUM(money) As Anual,
       SUM(CASE WHEN Month(FechaDeposito)=10 THEN money else 0 end) as monthly
  FROM Deposito
 WHERE FechaDeposito >= '2011-01-01' and FechaDeposito < '2012-01-01'
```